# Do DNS logs show a device’s name that’s behind a router?

Tags: dns, network-programming

Alright everyone, so I recently read on a Reddit post that a DNS server somehow can log a device’s name (e.g., Ray’s iPhone) in the logs.

Can someone on here explain to me how this is possible if someone is behind a router? I can’t imagine that this being something that is happening given the privacy implications here.

Is this something that people should be worrying about? I have never heard of this before, which somewhat surprises me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS - dynamic DNS used?

Comment: @user2864740 it didn’t give any context. I just was asking a general question and the person said that they can see a users device name on some authoritative name server logs they can see (Ray’s MacBook and the like). Can you clarify though how dynamic DNS might explain this? And when I am just using my iPhone to go to a website is it possible that my device name is getting logged with DNS query logs?

Comment: DNS _queries_ don’t send the name information. If this information is appearing elsewhere 1) it is being supplied by the client, somehow; 2) something, aside from vanilla DNS, is querying for and/or otherwise collecting this information from the machines.

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play - Network UPnP (and like other protocols). Again neither of these are related to DNS _queries_, rather a secondary announcement elected into by machines for discovery.

Comment: @user2864740 here is the link to the Reddit question. https://www.reddit.com/r/dns/comments/j11fy4/iterative_dns_log_question/                                                         Does this clarify what I am asking about? Are you saying that in this case something else must be going on?

Comment: @user2864740 I just asked for context in Reddit from the person posting. He just said that in the “query logs” for authoritative name servers it sometimes says device name, IP address, date and time, and the query.

Comment: Again, that information is not sent in a DNS query. The senders IP is naturally exposed, although this would be the IP of a router/NAT in many cases. If this information is logged with a name, such association is made independent of a DNS _query_ content.

Comment: @user2864740       In what circumstances would an authoritative name server be able to get this information and combine it? Like how would you suspect this would happen?

Comment: As no actual logs excerpts were provided, and this claim comes from a Reddit comment stream, it might be possible to guess the credence I’m giving to that without additional information.. Anyway http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/protocols/domain-name-system-dns/160-protocols-dns-query.html is a somewhat easy read on the structure of a DNS query. In 2020 it’d just be JSON >_<

Comment: From a logging/auditing perspective, it also adds little to no value to record the “name” of a client making a request, even if all DNS queries were direct (DNS levels and caching throw a huge wrench into such anyway). It is also slower to resolve back to names or employ lookups, which is not ideal in high activity logging. Logging the requesting IP is sufficient for general traffic analysis.

Comment: Perhaps the Reddit comments refer to the _domain name requested_? That information _is_ available. (And not the “name” of the machine making the request.)

Comment: In any case, OT for this site as there is no question related to _coding_ - I’ve voted to move to the General Computing.

Comment: @user2864740     Another person I was speaking with on Reddit mentioned that this may have occurred through edns0. They mentioned something about it being possible to mess around in there and adding in hostnames. Do you know if this theory has any credence? I was looking up edns0 to learn more, but I am not sure how edns0 works and who would have to do what to make this work.

Comment: With edns(0), clients can send additional information. So yes, it seems plausible that some implementations could leak more than a user might expect. A local endpoint DNS could definitely forward data upward to a recursive (and then the recursive to authoritative, eg).

Comment: @user2864740     A local endpoint dns would just be your isps DNS, right? In this case how would it work that this would still get past the router though? I’m guessing it would just be set up where this could only work if the router you are signing into is run by the same company/person that runs the dns you first connect to, right?